# Deploy YoloV7 Trained Model in Google Cloud Function

Tags: deep-learning, deployment, pytorch, google-cloud-functions, yolov7

I have trained yolov7 model .pt file and Now I want to deploy to it to Google Cloud Function which will receive photos name and storage address and return the bounding box of object in image .         I am not getting any definite path to do this.

I try to find a way to do the task but not finding any way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have the same question. I have a best.pt weight that was trained using a Yolov7 Notebook on Workbench, and now I would like to deploy this model to my Model Registry, so I could perform a Batch Prediction or Online Prediction. It seams like I can not import this model like any other AutoML trained model